# Get `useragent` property with CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, user-interface, user-agent

How can I get the `useragent` property with CakePHP built in tool?

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` not good enough?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make use of the inbuilt CakePHP function `env()`.

```
env('HTTP_USER_AGENT');
```

Comment: what other details of my user can i get

Comment: env is essentially a wrapper function, have a read up on the function here - http://book.cakephp.org/view/701/env

Comment: Documentation for `env` [here](http://api.cakephp.org/2.2/function-env.html) and [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#global-functions)

Answer (score 4):

For CakePHP 4.x, in Controller object:

```php
$ua = $this->getRequest()->getHeaderLine('User-Agent');
```